# reading values from serialport

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a program in unity that reads values from serialport and my program freezes beacuse of `serial.ReadLine()` and if i change it to `serial.ReadByte()` it reads bytes, and now only option is i want to know how to convert these bytes to string.
My code is as following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class leti3 : MonoBehaviour {

    public SerialPort serial = new SerialPort("COM5", 115200);
    public GameObject personaje;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        serial.Open();
        //serial.ReadTimeout = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (serial.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
            print(serial.ReadByte()); //reads bytes
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NB you'll likely want to set the many qualities .Handshake, .DataBits, timeouts etc.

Answer (score 4):

`ReadLine` is blocking. It will block execution until it reaches the end of a line. You want to instead use the [DataRecieved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

In the handler you can use [ReadExisting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the string currently in the buffer. You will have to manage that the string may only be part of the message you received.

Or you can read bytes into an array and then use [Encoding.GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) with the appropriate encoding.

If you can't use `DataRecieved` and have to use the blocking `ReadByte`, then you ought to still be able to do something like this in your update:

```
var toRead = serial.BytesToRead();    // make sure there actually are bytes to read first
for (int i=0; i < toRead; i++)
{
    // where msgArray is an array for storing the incoming bytes
    // and idx is the current idx in that array
    msgArray[idx] = serial.ReadByte();  // this should be quick, because it's already 
                                        // in the buffer
    if (msgArray[idx] = newLineChar)    // whatever newLineChar you are using
    {
        // Read your string
        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgArray,0,idx);   // or whatever encoding you 
                                                              // are using
        idx = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       idx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity uses the old version of Mono and `DataRecieved` does not work in this version. Last time I checked, you can send to Serial but can't receive. This applies even when using Thread. His only option seems to be to make a plugin in C++. Sounds crazy but that's how most Unity users use the Serial port until this is fixed.

Comment: yeah it really isnt working properly, beacuse in simple c# program readline is working great but not in unity

Comment: @anthraxa: Then you can still `ReadByte` into an array and then use `Encoding.GetString` to convert it to a string once you reach the end of the line.

Comment: yeah that is the only option i know, thanks for your help guys